# 'advise of' vs 'advise on' vs 'advise + some other preposition'

Tags: difference, legalese

What are the similarities and differences? Google produced http://www.grammarly.com/answers/questions/1959-advise-someone-of-something/#answer_2105:

> ...We use 'to advise someone of something' when we are warning someone....

I doubt the above, because definition 1.2 http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/advise?q=advise+ says nothing about any element of "warning"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"We advise someone of <something>" is something a lawyer might say.  It means "We cover our ass by warning someone about <something>.  We might tell them enough about <something> that they can make an intelligent decision, or we might just mention it and pretend that they will consider it.  If later on, that <something> bites them in the ass, we can say 'We told you so'; hopefully that will be enough to get us out of trouble."

"We advise on <issue>" is something a trusted advisor might say.  It means "We provide good-intentioned advice about <issue>".

"Cover your ass" (CYA) is an expression that means "use a disclaimer to avoid getting bitten in the ass".  The first paragraph has a typical example of such a CYA.

"Bitten in the ass" is an expression that means "got an unpleasant surprise from something you were either unaware of, or thought was safe to ignore".